# Infinite loop trouble in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, infinite-loop

when I run the `for` loop towards the bottom of this code I get an infinite loop that outputs the output in the `if` statement every single time with `i` being incremented each time and doesn't stop. I'm pretty sure it's a small problem that I just can't put my finger on...

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2johnson_pp1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Please enter the species with the higher" + 
                          " population first\n");
        System.out.printf("Enter the name of your first species ");
        String Species1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Enter the species' population: ");
        int Pop1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Enter the species' growth rate: ");
        int Growth1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Enter the name of your second species: ");
        String Species2 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Enter the species' population: ");
        int Pop2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Enter the species' growth rate: ");
        int Growth2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (Pop2 > Pop1) {
            System.out.printf("The first population must be higher. \n");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        Species input1 = new Species();
        input1.name = Species1;
        input1.population = Pop1;
        input1.growthRate = Growth1;

        Species input2 = new Species();
        input2.name = Species2;
        input2.population = Pop2;
        input2.growthRate = Growth2;

        if ((input1.predictPopulation(1) - input2.predictPopulation(1)) <= 
            (input1.predictPopulation(2) - input2.predictPopulation(2))){

            System.out.printf(Species2 + " will never out-populate " + 
                              Species1 + "\n");
        }
        else {

            for (int i = 0; input2.predictPopulation(i) <= 
                            input1.predictPopulation(i); i++) {

                if (input2.predictPopulation(i) == input1.predictPopulation(i)) {
                    System.out.printf(" will out-populate \n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public int predictPopulation(int years)
        {
            int result = 0;
            double populationAmount = population;
            int count = years;
            while ((count > 0) && (populationAmount > 0))
            {
                populationAmount = (populationAmount +
                              (growthRate / 100) * populationAmount);
                count--;
            }
            if (populationAmount > 0)
                result = (int)populationAmount;

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Impossible question to answer if you don't show what `predictPopulation()` does.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, as you haven't shown the definition of `predictPopulation()`.  All that can be said is that clearly `input2.predictPopulation(i)` never exceeds `input1.predictPopulation(i)`.

Comment: Sorry, guys I got sidetracked while posting thise. predictPopulation() is up there now

Comment: I suggest you step through your program in the debugger to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
        if (Pop2 > Pop1) {
            Species2 = Species1;
            Pop2 = Pop1;
            Growth1 = Growth2;
        }
```

does not make sense. Apparently what you intend is to "swap" the values for the two populations, but instead, you just cause the two populations to be identical, so that for any value of `years`, `predictPopulation(years)` will be the same for both objects.

---

**Edited to add:** This test:

```
        if ((input1.predictPopulation(1) - input2.predictPopulation(1)) < 
            (input1.predictPopulation(2) - input2.predictPopulation(2)))
```

is not a valid way to see whether species 2 will eventually overtake species 1. If species 2 has a greater *proportional* growth rate (`growthRate`), then it will eventually overtake species 1, even if during the first few years, it has a lower *absolute* growth rate. (This only tangentially relates to your infinite loop — [Dampsquid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211614/dampsquid) points out that you wouldn't have had the infinite loop if you'd had `<=` instead of `<` — but it's a problem you need to fix.)

Comment: Also if ((input1.predictPopulation(1) - input2.predictPopulation(1)) < 
            (input1.predictPopulation(2) - input2.predictPopulation(2))) needs a <= to catch identical growth popluations

Comment: @Dampsquid: Good point, thanks. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @Dampsquid: Actually, on second thought . . . it's more complicated than that. The current test is wrong in general, not just for using a `<` rather than a `<=`. If `input1` starts out with a very tiny population, then it might start out *seeming* to grow more slowly (since growth is proportional to population), but still end up overtaking `input2` (since the one with the greater `growthRate` will always end up bigger in the long term).

Comment: Are you sure? Because the population increases more and more each year.

Comment: @ruakh: hmm very true, this homework needs much more thinking about, glad its not mine (finished homework decades ago thankfully)

Comment: @WadeJ: Yes, I'm sure. Suppose that the populations start out at `100` and `200`, with growth rates `90%` and `50%` (respectively). In the first year, the first population gains only `90` (giving `190`), while the second gains `100` (giving `300`), so the difference increases; but in the second year, the first population gains `171` (giving `361`), while the second gains only `150` (giving `450`), so the difference is already less than it was initially. In the third year, the first population gains `324.9` (giving `685.9`, or rather `685`), while the second gains only `225` (giving [continued]

Comment: @WadeJ: [continued] `675`), meaning that the first population has overtaken the second -- in just three years -- even though it increased *less* in the first year.

Comment: thinking on it if growth2 > growth1, as long as growth2*pop2 >=1 in the first year pop2 will eventually overtake pop1 as it has a greater exponential growth

Comment: @ruakh I see what you're saying. But the book says to implement that error message in there, so I'm just going to keep it in there. So I'm technically following the problem. :(
But now I have another problem. I have tweaked the code and now if all the parameters are meant and triggers none of my error messages the program just exits without saying anything. I have NO clue what I did.I'll edit my question with the new code. If you wouldn't mind helping me again. :)

Comment: @WadeJ: If my answer helped you to address your existing problem, then if I may say so, I think you should accept it, and post a new question with your new problem.

Comment: @ruakh Oh sorry, I just gave it a vote up, instead of accepting, sorry. I just didn't want to post a whole new question with almost the exact same code.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; input2.predictPopulation(i) <= 
>                     input1.predictPopulation(i); i++) {
> ```

The population of input1 is never becoming less then input2 this has to do with one of the following:

1. input1 is getting a parameter value that would not allow it's "population" to become less then input2 (check ranges of inputs to make sure this can occur, maybe something like making sure that input2's growth rate is > input1)
2. There is something wrong with the class itself that is forcing input1 to always be equal to or greater then input2.

EDIT: since you have posted the code for predictPopulation it looks like it is number one. Make sure that your growth rate for input2 is always greater then input1.